# Idea for developing an expert system using Drools expert

Tags: java, drools, expert-system

I want to develop tax advisory system using Drools expert. The idea of such system is able to
select the Tax rules to calculate tax amount and suggest recommendation(s) to reduce tax payment.

For tax calculation,
Suppose a taxpayer is physician. He earned income in form of salary. The deduction rate for his income earned 
is 40% of totally earned but not exceeding 60,000. He has self allowance because he is a citizen of his country.
The fomular of tax calculation is 
Total income - deduction of income - allowance = net income

This net income will be use in tax computation methods : progressive and fix rate

the progressive is always be selected whereas fix rate method will be selected if taxpayer income
is not in form of salary.

After the system selected the tax computation method and computed already. 
It should be able to suggest tax reduction plan.

From the previous example, a physician earned income in form of salary. The salary income can be deducted
40% of total earned but not exceeding 60,000 . However, if he declare himself as
medical profession, not an employee of a hospital , he will allow to deduct his income upto 60%.

My wish expert system could suggest taxpayer to do something like this.

Could Drools experts capable to do something like this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if all you want to know is whether drools can handle this, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes  drools can handle it, but you need to analyze the best way to model the problem. You can basically solve this problem using some decision tables or just plain rules, depending on the model that you create to represent the domain concepts.

Cheers